# How to fix this traits with `super`?

Tags: scala, super, traits

Scala code:

```
trait Logger {
  def log(msg: String)
}

trait TimeLogger extends Logger {
  def log(msg: String) = super.log(new Date + ": " + msg)
}

class MyApp extends TimeLogger {
  override def log(msg: String): Unit = println(msg)

  log("Hello")
}

new MyApp()
```

When I compile it, it reports error:

```
Error:(12, 34) method log in trait Logger is accessed from super. It may not be abstract unless it is overridden by a member declared `abstract' and `override'
    def log(msg: String) = super.log(new Date + ": " + msg)
                                 ^
```

I'm not quite understand it, why should I declared an `abstract` and `override` `log` method? How to fix it?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645172/why-is-abstract-override-required-not-override-alone-in-subtrait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala traits, in the manner you're using `Log` are essentially interfaces, i.e. specifications of behavior. So your types

```
trait Logger {
  def log(msg: String)
}

trait TimeLogger extends Logger {
  def log(msg: String) = super.log(new Date + ": " + msg)
}
```

are saying that an instance of a `Logger` will provide it's own implementation of `log(msg: String)`. Since 'log' is not implemented in `Logger`, it's impossible to call it with `super.`.

However, if you were to call `super.log` from `MyApp` then it would exercise the `TimeLogger.log` call.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, you don't have an implementation of `log` in your `Logger` trait. By calling `super.log` from `TimeLogger`, you are calling an unimplemented method.

It seems you are attempting to override a method, but not completely define it. You cannot call the method you are overriding from its own implementation (unless you want recursion). Instead of calling `super.log`, which is not implemented, I believe you actually want to call the **implementation** of the logging from a child class. You certainly cannot use the same function prototype for both.

Perhaps you could define `TimeLogger` and `MyApp` in the following way:

```
trait TimeLogger extends Logger {
  def logImpl(msg: String)
  def log(msg: String) = logImpl(new Date + ": " + msg)
}

class MyApp extends TimeLogger {
  override def logImpl(msg: String): Unit = println(msg)

  log("Hello")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you are trying to decorate the log function of any logger implementation with a timestamp.

As a result you would like to use the `TimeLogger` trait as a *Decorator* for `Logger` implementations that delegate to say `println`, `Log4j`, maybe even `android.Log`.

There are two ways (I can think of) how you can achieve something like that:

1)

```
trait Logger {
  def log(msg: String): Unit
}

class PrintStreamLogger extends Logger {
  def log(msg: String): Unit = println(msg)
}

abstract class TimeLogger(loggerImpl: Logger) extends Logger {
  def log(msg: String): Unit = loggerImpl.log(new Date + ": " + msg)
}

class MyApp extends TimeLogger(new PrintStreamLogger) {
  log("Hello")
}
```

2)

```
trait Logger {
  def log(msg: String): Unit = logImpl(msg)

  protected def logImpl(msg: String): Unit
}

trait TimeLogger {
  loggerImpl: Logger =>
  override def log(msg: String): Unit =
    loggerImpl.logImpl(s"${new Date}: $msg")
}

class MyApp extends Logger with TimeLogger {
  protected def logImpl(msg: String): Unit = println(msg)
  log("Hello")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another way to fix it by creating a trait `PrintLogger` which extends `Logger`, and then mix both of them in `MyApp`:

```
trait Logger {
  def log(msg: String)
}

trait PrintLogger extends Logger {
  override def log(msg: String): Unit = println(msg)
}

trait TimeLogger extends Logger {
  abstract override def log(msg: String) = super.log(new Date + ": " + msg)
}

class MyApp extends PrintLogger with TimeLogger {
  log("Hello")
}

new MyApp()
```

Comment: This solution is quite hacky. Your `TimeLogger` trait **requires** an intermediate parent which **implements** logger, even though its declaration does not specify so. The class `MyApp` wouldn't even compile had you reversed the order of the extended traits. When you require an implementation of a trait, it is much better to use the cake pattern in a similar way Sascha Kolberg does in his answer.