# why method needs 'abstract override' modifier

Tags: scala

```
trait Base {
  def someMethod: Unit
}

trait SomeTrait extends Base {
  abstract override def someMethod: Unit = ???
}

class SomeTraitImp extends SomeTrait with Base {
  override def someMethod: Unit = ???
}
```

Error message states:

> Error: overriding method someMethod in trait SomeTrait of type => Unit;
>    method someMethod needs `abstract override' modifiers
>         override def someMethod: Unit = ???

Why Scala compiler restricts me from overriding this method without marking it as an abstract?

**Edit:**

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645172/why-is-abstract-override-required-not-override-alone-in-subtrait) answer and it explains why `abstract` keyword required on method when we reference to `super` which may not have implementation yet.

In my case I'm just trying to override `someMethod` in `SomeTrait` by brand new implementation and not trying to call `super.someMethod`.

Is this override can break something at runtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "abstract override" required not "override" alone in subtrait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645172/why-is-abstract-override-required-not-override-alone-in-subtrait)

Comment: Can you let us know which Scala version you are using, and give some real code that shows this error?

Comment: @Tim scala 2.12.7. this is the real code that shows the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have `abstract override`, it must override a concrete implementation for the whole thing to become concrete.

This works:

```
trait Foo extends Base { def someMethod: Unit = ??? }
class SomeTraitImp extends Foo with SomeTrait
```

Because `SomeTrait.someMethod` overrides a concrete implementation in `Foo`.
This does not:

```
class SomeTraitImp extends SomeTrait with Foo
```

Because a concrete method in `Foo` is trying to override an `abstract override` in `SomeTraitImpl`.

Your example is essentially the same as last snippet, except your override is in the class itself rather than in `Foo`.

And to answer your last question, yes, this would break at runtime if it was allowed. Consider this:

```
 trait Foo { def foo: String }
 trait Bar extends Foo { abstract override def foo = super.foo + "bar" }
 class Baz extends Foo with Bar { override def foo = super.foo + "baz" }

 println(new Baz().foo)
```

If this compiled, it would trow an exception at runtime, because `super.foo` in `Baz` calls `Bar`'s `foo`, which calls `super.foo`, which refers to `Foo.foo`, which is abstract.

Comment: The question is why override _without a `super` call_ is unsafe.

Comment: @Dima and what if we don't have `super.foo` call in Baz. Only `def foo = "baz" ` ? Is it still unsafe?

Comment: @Dima and also question abut this `class SomeTraitImp extends SomeTrait with Foo`. Here we have `SomeTrait` containing abstract implementation overriding concrete implementation in `Foo` so I supposed that as we have concrete implementation we can say that whole `SomeTraitImp` is concrete because abstract method can call non-abstract code if needed.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko It is not _actually_ unsafe without the `super` call, but the idea is that you _declare_ a method as `abstract override`  to say "this trait must  be overriding a concrete implementation". Just like you cannot instantiate an abstract class, even if it has no actual abstract members.

Comment: In `class SomeTraitImp extends SomeTrait with Foo`,  `SomeTrait` does _not_ override implementation of `Foo` (it goes left to right, so `Foo` overrides `SomeTrait`, the other way around), `SomeTrait`'s super in this case is `Base`.

Comment: @Dima just last question. Let's say I have traits `A` and `B`. And I'm creating `val` like this `val v = new  A with B { ... } `. Can I say that this block `{ ... }` is the same as if I could write something like this `val v = new  A with B with { ... } ` . Kind of anonymous class or trait with all linerization/overriding rules applied as if I create this trait separately and then join it as regular trait?

Comment: `A with B { ... }` is the same as `class C extends A with B { ... }`, if that's what you are asking.